# Is it possible to upload images to folder out side web root using Kendo Image Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo Image Browser in my asp.net MVC application. I need to upload images out side web root using Kendo Image Browser.
Currently content root folder is set as

```
    private const string contentFolderRoot = "~/Upload/Images";
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not possible at all, Kendo Image Browser or not. This is for security. If you need to access a directory outside of the document root, then you need to add a virtual directory to your site, pointing to that outside directory. Which effectively gives the IIS site access to that directory as well, since it's now inside it's document root.